# trouble getting css properties in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

**UPDATE:** here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqXZP/2/. If you view it on Chrome and then on firefox you will see the problem.

I'm trying to get the complete padding string from an element. My original code read something like this:

```
var totalPaddingString = $(element).css("padding"); //Chrome returns "10px 0px 9px 10px" etc.

//do stuff with `totalPaddingString` here
```

This works fine in Chrome. However, when I try using the `.css()` method in Firefox and IE, an empty string is returned. At first I thought it was a problem with how these two browsers use jQuery so I switched to native Javascript properties:

```
var totalPaddingString = element.style.padding;
```

But even this returns an empty string. Has anyone else run into this problem? Any advice?

Comment: Could you please show a complete example that exhibits the behavior (including HTML), preferably with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? `$.css()` certainly (usually) does work in Firefox and IE.

Comment: @Juhana-- here is the fiddle. If you view it in both browsers youll see that the padding values are returned in Chrome but not IE or Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqXZP/2/

Comment: Please leave a comment before you downvote. This seems to be a legitimate problem.

Comment: This is not a `css()` issue.  [Working fine with another property](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqXZP/3/) because shorthand CSS properties like `padding` are [not supported](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`.css()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.

Comment: It's "not supported" which means that you can't trust what the return value is. Apparently Chrome stores the shorthand value but FF and IE don't.

Comment: It's not a matter of storing.  It's a matter of what `getComputedStyle` returns.  Depending on how you read it, the spec for `getComputedStyle` requires returning empty string for shorthands.